# Napa App: _spPageContextInfo is not defined

Tags: development, 2013, sharepoint-addin

Am creating a vanilla Napa app and am seeking to reference the host URL as follows:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
```

Yet _`spPageContextInfo` is being flagged as `undefined`. From what I have read this should be baked into SharePoint, so I cannot understand why it is not defined.

I'm sure the solution is simple, but can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the "SharePoint:SharePointForm" control to your page body.

[enter link description here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111324/sppagecontextinfo-is-undefined-in-client-web-part/135978#135978)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this extremely similar question [Accessing a list from app web on host site generates access denied](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60702/accessing-a-list-from-app-web-on-host-site-generates-access-denied)

It has the answer I suppose!

Comment: Similar, but not a duplicate as I see it ;-)

Comment: No I realized it was not the same question, but the same answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to benefit from these URLs you would need to pass in the proper Tokens, which can than be retrieved as explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163816.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179886.aspx

I would even argue that _spPageContextInfo  is not to be used in the a SharePoint app (mainly used it in Farm solutions) but rather use the token to build your context properly. Examples for using JSOM available also here http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj163201.aspx

Answer (score 0):

_spPageContextInfo can be used in a page in a SharePoint-Hosted app. You will get a "squigly" in the editor because it the _spPageContextInfo object is added to the page dynamically, thus the editor is not aware of it.

Simple example using _spPageContextInfo :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to necessarily reference a master page in your SharePoint app to get _spPageContextInfo to load.

What is required is the addition of the `<asp:ScriptMananger>` control to your App or AppPart page. The control has to live in a `<form runat="server">` so be sure to add that too.

```
    <body>

    <form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />
<!-- Your code goes here -->
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Using a webform in a Provider-Hosted app, I haven't been able to get this to work - I still get "_spPageContextInfo is not defined" Do you have more information on this?